# ActionScript 3.0 addChild throwing error

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, addchild

basically my issue is i got my main class..which has a variable which is the object holding my levels. but when i try to add the child to the stage i get an error...i have never had this error before and i am very confused. The error i get is this

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Levels/spawn(). Expected 0, got 1.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at Main()

here is my main class:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public static var game:Levels = new Levels();

        public function Main() {
            game = new Levels();
            addChild(game); //this triggers my error
            game.y = 352;
        }

    }

    }
```

here my is my levels class

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;


    public class Levels extends MovieClip
    {

        var platforms:Array = new Array();

        var gravity:Number = 0;
        var rPress:Boolean = false;
        var lPress:Boolean = false;

        var falling:Boolean = false;
        var jumping:Boolean = false;

        var velX:Number = 0;
        var velY:Number = 0;

        var a:int = 0;

        public function Levels()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, spawn);
        }
        function spawn()
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, spawn);
            getMap();
            this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kPress);
            this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, kReleased);
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
        function getMap()
        {
            platforms.pop();
            for (var a:int = 0; a < numChildren; a ++)
            {
                if (getChildAt(a) is Terrain)
                {
                    platforms.push(getChildAt(a).getRect(this));
                }
            }
        }
        function kPress(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                lPress = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                rPress = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 32)
            {
                if (jumping == false)
                {
                    gravity = -25;
                    jumping = true;
                }

            }
        }
        function kReleased(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                lPress = false;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                rPress = false;
            }
        }
        function loop(event:Event)
        {
            velX = 0;

            if (rPress == true)
            {
                velX = 7;
            }
            if (lPress == true)
            {
                velX = -7;
            }
            velY = gravity;
            _player.y +=  velY;
            gravity +=  2;

            for (a = 0; a < platforms.length; a ++)
            {
                if (_player.getRect(this).intersects(platforms[a]))
                {
                    if (velY > 0)
                    {
                        jumping = false;
                        _player.y = platforms[a].top - _player.height;
                        gravity = 0;
                    }
                    else if (velY < 0)
                    {

                        _player.y = platforms[a].bottom;
                        gravity = 0;

                    }
                }
            }
            _player.x +=  velX;
            if (rPress == true)
            {

                if (_player.x + _player.width / 2 > 336 + x * -1 && x + width > 640)
                {

                    x -=  velX;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_player.x + _player.width / 2 > 304 + x * -1 && x < 0)
                {

                    x -=  velX;
                }
            }
            for (a = 0; a < platforms.length; a ++)
            {
                if (_player.getRect(this).intersects(platforms[a]))
                {
                    if (velX == 7)
                    {
                        _player.x = platforms[a].x - _player.width;
                        x +=  velX;
                    }
                    if (velX == -7)
                    {
                           _player.x=platforms[a].x+platforms[a].width;
                        x +=  velX;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spawn` method is a handler for the `addedToStage` event so it expects the event object as a parameter:

```
function spawn(event:Event)
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, spawn);
    getMap();
    this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kPress);
    this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, kReleased);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}
```

Comment: Easy mistake to make! Remember to accept the answer if it helped you out.